# Dell PowerEdge R540 Installing RHEL 5.3 Legacy OS on new hardware

Tags: centos, redhat, installation, centos5, rhel5

I have a new (**2020) Dell Power Edge R540 x86-64 Server**. It will run a vendor supplied cobol application and requires **RHEL 5.3 or CENT OS 5.3** for the operating system. Yes I agree this is frustrating that the vendor has not upgraded code.

The Dell R540 server cam installed with Red Hat 8.2 and configured with a RAID5 virtual disk.

**I am currently unable to boot off the RHEL 5.3 CD #1 when pressing F11 and selecting the boot device.**

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE:  Solved with virtualization

RHEL 8.2 and kvm, libvirt.

I created a bridge for the guest vm , mounted on loopback the rhel 5.3 dvd downloaded from red hat, and did a http install. Then used rsync with an exclusion list to copy the source server to target.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where you should virtualize the workload.

Use VMware ESXi or an open-source alternative to leverage modern hardware, coupled with a guest OS running the preferred variant of RHEL.

Lean on your vendor to provide customer references or other examples of how this is handled in their other environments.